# Angular Material 2 - Website not rendering fullscreen correctly

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to slightly rewrite my application. I have in the past only created applications with Sidenavs, however now I don't need it in a website i'm working on. The issue is I can't seem to find a way to remove the sidenav container without it breaking the background image, the nav bar being sticky, etc. I can't seem to find anything on material.angular.io that refers to anything like this or can fix this.

If anyone knows how to remedy this issue please point me to the documentation/ what I can change to fix this.

[Github for the site](https://github.com/buffet-time/themeathon.com/tree/master/src/app)

With Mat-Sidenav-Container 
[image]

Sidenav container as a div
[image]

div with css taken from the sidenav container 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick fix

`app.component.html`

```
<!-- <mat-sidenav-container fullscreen class="sidenav-container"> -->
<!-- <mat-toolbar class="toolbar"> -->
<!-- <div class="social-media" id="discord" (click)="navigateToDiscord()"> -->
<!-- <img src="../../assets/discord.png"> -->
<!-- </div> -->
<!--  -->
<!-- <div class="social-media" (click)="navigateToTwitch()"> -->
<!-- <img src="../../assets/twitch.png"> -->
<!-- </div> -->
<!--  -->
<!-- <div class="social-media" (click)="navigateToTwitter()"> -->
<!-- <img src="../../assets/twitter.png"> -->
<!-- </div> -->
<!--  -->
<!-- <div class="social-media" (click)="navigateToYoutube()"> -->
<!-- <img src="../../assets/youtube.png"> -->
<!-- </div> -->
<!--  -->
<!-- <div class="themeathon-name"> -->
<!-- <div class="name-span"> -->
<!-- <span>THEMEATHON</span> -->
<!-- </div> -->
<!-- </div> -->
<!-- </mat-toolbar> -->
<!--  -->
<!-- <stream-component></stream-component> -->
<!--  -->
<!-- </mat-sidenav-container> -->



<div class="background">

    <div class="toolbar">
        <div class="social-media-container">
            <div class="social-media" id="discord" (click)="navigateToDiscord()">
                <img src="../../assets/discord.png">
            </div>

            <div class="social-media" (click)="navigateToTwitch()">
                <img src="../../assets/twitch.png">
            </div>

            <div class="social-media" (click)="navigateToTwitter()">
                <img src="../../assets/twitter.png">
            </div>

            <div class="social-media" (click)="navigateToYoutube()">
                <img src="../../assets/youtube.png">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="themeathon-name">
            <div class="name-span">
                <span>THEMEATHON</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <stream-component></stream-component>
</div>
```

Added css class `.background` at `app.component.css`

```
.background {
    background-image: url(../../assets/japan.jpg);
}
 .toolbar {
    top: 0;
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    z-index: 50;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    height: 70px;
}

.social-media-container,
.themeathon-name {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 16px);
}

.social-media {
    padding-top: 6px;
    margin: 0 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline;
}

.social-media img {
    fill: #fff;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}

.social-media-text {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 6px;
}

.themeathon-name {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.themeathon-name span {
    font-family: SAMURAI, Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto 26%;
}
```

[image]
Is that what you are after?

Here is the screen when I move down
[image]

Comment: The sidenav container class that if you make it just a div, has  background-image.

Comment: Also you removed the navbar. I'm just trying to get rid of the Sidenav component but not have the background stay in one place, and have the website punched in

Comment: sorry, I get you wrong. Just updated my solution with navbar

Comment: or what else do you want?

Comment: As i was saying, that doesn't fix the issue that if you scroll down the background doesnt move down.

Comment: see the added image when I scroll down. You can see the background there

Comment: Do you want I do a PR on you repo so you can have a look?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171275/discussion-between-sugarme-and-buffet-time).

Comment: I think I just forgot to add `.background` class to css. See the updated. I made a PR to your repos as well.

Comment: If it is what you want, please accept it as answer.

Comment: The PR was not. It has the same issue of not being the same as when its the sidenav container. If you do your changes and run the app and then compare it to themeathon.com you'll notice the background looks different and the whole app is punched in.